# Why is the WWF pending games ("Your turn") area replaced w/ a column of "Bonus & Reward"gift boxes?

Tags: words-with-friends

The left portion of the screen usually lists "Your turn" games, and under that "Their turn" ones and recent win/loss history. Suddenly, it's been replaced with a column full of "Bonus & Reward" images. I can't see pending games, pick the one I want to play first, etc. Cannot figure out how to put it back to normal. Any ideas?
[image: The Screen]

Comment: Uhhhh... What? (I don't understand this question at all)

Comment: @aytimothy The left-hand side normally lists the matches a user is playing/has played. Either they updated and changed it or OP changed a setting, and now it's stuck at seen above.